# FancyTree - Only loads Persist state after page refresh

Tags: jquery, fancytree

So I have a FancyTree which is working fine. I want to maintain the state of the Tree when user moves to another Page. And I am following this link to achieve this;  http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-persist.html#

I am loading all my pages using Ajax, When I reload the website using `Ctrl + F5`, and navigate to the Page with Tree the Previous state is loaded from Local Storage. Which is fine.

When I refresh the entire page:

[image]

But when I go to another page using ajax and come back to the Page with Tree, It does not load the Previous state.

When I load the View using Ajax:

[image]

This is my Code:

```
    var glyph_opts = {
        map: {
            doc: "fa fa-truck",
            docOpen: "fa fa-truck",
            checkbox: "glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
            checkboxSelected: "glyphicon glyphicon-check",
            checkboxUnknown: "glyphicon glyphicon-share",
            dragHelper: "glyphicon glyphicon-play",
            dropMarker: "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right",
            error: "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign",
            expanderClosed: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
            expanderLazy: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
            expanderOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign",
            folder: "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close",
            folderOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open",
            loading: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
        }
    };

    $("#tree").fancytree({
        extensions: ["glyph", "filter", "persist"],
        persist: {
            expandLazy: true,
            // fireActivate: true,    // false: suppress `activate` event after active node was restored
            overrideSource: true,  // true: cookie takes precedence over `source` data attributes.
            store: "auto" // 'cookie', 'local': use localStore, 'session': sessionStore
        },
        source: $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CompaniesTree", "Dashboard")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        }),
        activate: function (event, data) {

            if (data.node.data.GroupType === 4) {
                var model = {
                    key: data.node.key,
                    data: data.node.data
                };

            }
            return true;
        },
        iconClass: function (event, data) {
            if (data.node.data.GroupType === 1) {
                return "fa fa-desktop";
            }
            if (data.node.data.GroupType === 2) {
                return "fa fa-sitemap";
            }
        },
        selectMode: 2,
        init: function (event, data) {
            data.tree.debug(event.type, data);
        },
        restore: function (event, data) {
            data.tree.debug(event.type, data);
        },
        loadChildren: function (event, data) {
            data.node.debug(event.type, data);
        },

        quicksearch: true,
        filter: {
            //http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-filter.html#
            //autoApply: true,  // Re-apply last filter if lazy data is loaded
            counter: false,  // Show a badge with number of matching child nodes near parent icons
            fuzzy: false,  // Match single characters in order, e.g. 'fb' will match 'FooBar'
            hideExpandedCounter: true,  // Hide counter badge, when parent is expanded
            mode: "hide"  // Grayout unmatched nodes (pass "hide" to remove unmatched node instead)
        },
        glyph: glyph_opts,
        lazyLoad: function (event, data) {

            var model = {
                key: data.node.key,
                data: data.node.data
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChildItems", "Dashboard")',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                success: function (response) {
                    data.result = response;
                }
            });
        }

    });

    var tree = $("#tree").data("ui-fancytree").getTree();
```

I even checked the Session Storage and see that the data for Fancy Tree state is saved - There are NO Errors in `Console`

[image]

Comment: Posting the ajax call where you load the page might help find the problem. How do you call your fancytree code when the page is loaded?

Comment: That code is already posted in the Question

Comment: I meant the code you use to navigate between pages. I can only see the code that initializes the tree

Comment: It's a simple Ajax request. Request returns HTML.partial view and then HTML is assigned to a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use the [cookiePrefix](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtPersist#options) configuration option.

**Explanation:**

This happens because each time you load the page, you are creating a new FancyTree instance. The Fancytree plugin keeps track of all instances it creates, assigning each new one an unique ID and a namespace. From the fancytree source code:

```
function Fancytree(widget) {
    // some other code ...
    this._id = $.ui.fancytree._nextId++;
    this._ns = ".fancytree-" + this._id; // append for namespaced events
    // some other code ...
}
```

By default, the namespace used by the persistence plugin is `fancytree-[instance-ID]-`. So, for each new instance, it sets its own cookie. Fortunately, you can also manually set the namespace to use with the configuration option [cookiePrefix](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtPersist#options):

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    extensions: ["glyph", "filter", "persist"],
    persist: {
        cookiePrefix: 'fancytree-1-',
        expandLazy: true,
        overrideSource: true,  // true: cookie takes precedence over `source` data attributes.
        store: "auto" // 'cookie', 'local': use localStore, 'session': sessionStore
    },
    // rest of the config ...
});
```

This way, the persistence plugin will always use the same namespace for setting and getting the cookie.

Comment: @Dawood You're welcome. I had some fun figuring out what was happening